# Filpping a coin infinitely many times

Tags: probability, infinity

If a coin was flipped an infinite number of times, is it guaranteed to be heads at least once?

Comment: "was flipped an infinite number of times"? So when exactly did this experiment complete?

Comment: What do you mean by "guaranteed"? You pay me a premium now, then flip the coin an infinite number of times, and afterwards I pay you much more back if there are no heads?

Comment: Not if it has tails on both sides

Comment: For $n$ coin flips (of unbiased coin with one tail and one head): on average, you'll get $n/2$ heads and $n/2$ tails. The greater the value of $n$, the more precise this average will be.

Comment: Probability $1$ that it will land at least once on its edge too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the probability of the coin landing on heads is greater than $0$, then, the probability that when tossed infinitely many times a heads will come up is $1$. That does not guarantee though that a heads will come up. In infinite probability spaces an event may have probability $0$ and still it may occur, and an event may have probability $1$, yet fail to occur.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "guaranteed."  The probability that all flips will be tails is 0 (hence the probability that there is at least one head is 1).

Answer (score 0):

$P[\text{At least one head}]= \lim_{n \to \infty}(1-P[\text{tails in all n times}])\\=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1-(1-p)^n)=1$.

So if you have a coin with probability of head $p$ and tosses are independent.